# После ввода команды выхода программа не завершается

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

Выполняю задание, данное в книге "укус питона" - создать адресную книгу.

Сейчас ковыряю функцию добавления контакта. Хочу, чтобы при вводе команды "Выход" или "Exit" в поле имени или контактной инф-ции программа завершалась, но программа не завершается после ввода команды выхода в поле имени, завершается только после ввода команды выхода в поле контактных данных.

Ввод следующий:

*Введите команду: доб*
*Введите имя и номер телефона.*
*Введите имя:  Геннадий Радионович*
*Введите контактную информацию:  79878787878*
*Введите имя:  Игнат Коловрат*
*Введите контактную информацию:  797777777*
*Введите имя:  выход*
*Введите контактную информацию:  ВЫХОД!*
*{'Геннадий Радионович': '79878787878', 'Игнат Коловрат': '797777777'}*
_

Не понимаю, почему при передаче keyName команды выхода программа не завершается. Прошу подсказать, как можно поправить ситуацию.

```py
...
    while True:
        keyName = Contact.contactName(print('Введите имя: ', end=' '))
        valueContact = Contact.contactDetails(print('Введите контактную информацию: ', end=' '))
        if keyName.startswith('вых'.lower()) or keyName.startswith('ex'.lower()) \
                or valueContact.startswith('вых'.lower()) or valueContact.startswith('ex'.lower()):
            break
        else:
            ab[keyName] = valueContact
...
```

Пробовал разделить if statement на части, чтоб было так:

```py
...
        if keyName.startswith('вых'.lower()) or keyName.startswith('ex'.lower()):
            break
        elif valueContact.startswith('вых'.lower()) or valueContact.startswith('ex'.lower()):
            break
        else:
            ab[keyName] = valueContact
...
```

В надежде, что поможет, но не помогло.

Полная версия кода:

```py
import pickle

class Contact:
    def __init__(self, name, contacts):
        self.name = name
        self.contacts = contacts
    def contactName(self):
        name = input()
        return name
    def contactDetails(self):
        contacts = input()
        return contacts

def addContact():
    adressBook = 'ab.dat'
    ab = {}
    print('Введите имя и номер телефона.')
    while True:
        keyName = Contact.contactName(print('Введите имя: ', end=' '))
        valueContact = Contact.contactDetails(print('Введите контактную информацию: ', end=' '))
        if keyName.startswith('вых'.lower()) or keyName.startswith('ex'.lower()):
            break
        elif valueContact.startswith('вых'.lower()) or valueContact.startswith('ex'.lower()):
            break
        else:
            ab[keyName] = valueContact
    abf = open(adressBook, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(ab, abf)
    abf.close()
    abf = open(adressBook, 'rb')
    abprint = pickle.load(abf)
    print(abprint)


command = input('Введите команду: ')
try:
    if command.startswith('доб'.lower()) or command == 'add'.lower():
        exec(addContact())
except TypeError:
    pass
except EOFError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что не тот текст переводите в нижний регистр. Нужно так:

```
keyName.lower().startswith('вых')
```

И в других местах тоже.

Comment: все равно после ввода команды выхода предлагает ввести контактную информацию.  Введите команду: add
Введите имя и номер телефона.
Введите имя:  выход
Введите контактную информацию:  8717832
{} Введите команду: add
Введите имя и номер телефона.
Введите имя:  Boris
Введите контактную информацию:  871273812
Введите имя:  ex
Введите контактную информацию:  ex
{'Boris': '871273812'}

Comment: Ну разумеется, вы ж сначала запрашиваете то и это, а только потом обрабатываете полученный результат.

Comment: Догнал, спасибо! разделил if statement на два if и сделал ввод перед каждым if, работает.